# How to split an inbound stream on a delimiter character using Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I've been playing around with the experimental Akka Streams API a bit and I have a use case that I wanted to see how to implement.  For my use case, I have a `StreamTcp` based `Flow` that is being fed from binding the input stream of connections to my server socket.  The Flow that I have is based on `ByteString` data coming into it.  The data that is coming in is going to have a delimiter in it that means I should treat everything before the delimiter as one message and everything after and up to the next delimiter as the next message.  So playing around with a simpler example, using no sockets and just static text, this is what I came up with:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ FlowMaterializer, MaterializerSettings }
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }
import akka.util.ByteString

object BasicTransformation {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")

    val data = ByteString("Lorem Ipsum is simply.Dummy text of the printing.And typesetting industry.")

    Flow(data).
      splitWhen(c => c == '.').
      foreach{producer => 
        Flow(producer).
          filter(c => c != '.').
          fold(new StringBuilder)((sb, c) => sb.append(c.toChar)).
          map(_.toString).
          filter(!_.isEmpty).
          foreach(println(_)).
          consume(FlowMaterializer(MaterializerSettings()))
      }.
      onComplete(FlowMaterializer(MaterializerSettings())) {
        case any =>
          system.shutdown
      }
  }
}
```

The main function on the `Flow` that I found to accomplish my goal was `splitWhen`, which then produces additional sub-flows, one for each message per that `.` delimiter.  I then process each sub-flow with another pipeline of steps, finally printing the individual messages at the end.

This all seems a bit verbose, to accomplish what I thought to be a pretty simple and common use case.  So my question is, is there a cleaner and less verbose way to do this or is this the correct and preferred way to split a stream up by a delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this same question on the the Akka User's Group, I got some suggestions from Endre Varga and Viktor Klang (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/YsnwIAjQ3EE).  I ended up going with Endre's suggestion of a `Transformer` and then using the `transform` method on the `Flow`.  A slightly modified version of my previous example is contained below:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ FlowMaterializer, MaterializerSettings }
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }
import akka.util.ByteString
import akka.stream.Transformer
import akka.util.ByteStringBuilder

object BasicTransformation {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")                           
    implicit val mater = FlowMaterializer(MaterializerSettings())

    val data = List(
      ByteString("Lorem Ipsum is"), 
      ByteString(" simply.Dummy text of.The prin"), 
      ByteString("ting.And typesetting industry.")
    )
    Flow(data).transform(new PeriodDelimitedTransformer).foreach(println(_))
  }
}
```

With the definition of `PeriodDelimitedTransformer` being the following:

```
class PeriodDelimitedTransformer extends Transformer[ByteString,String]{
  val buffer = new ByteStringBuilder

  def onNext(msg:ByteString) = {    
    val msgString = msg.utf8String
    val delimIndex = msgString.indexOf('.')
    if (delimIndex == -1){
      buffer.append(msg)
      List.empty
    }
    else{
      val parts = msgString.split("\\.")
      val endsWithDelim = msgString.endsWith(".")

      buffer.putBytes(parts.head.getBytes())
      val currentPiece = buffer.result.utf8String            
      val otherPieces = parts.tail.dropRight(1).toList

      buffer.clear
      val lastPart = 
      if (endsWithDelim){
          List(parts.last)
      }
      else{
          buffer.putBytes(parts.last.getBytes())
          List.empty
      }           


      val result = currentPiece :: otherPieces ::: lastPart
      result
    }

  }  
}
```

So some of the complexity of my previous solution is rolled up into this `Transformer`, but this seems like the best approach.  In my initial solution, the stream ends up getting split into multiple sub-streams and that's not really what I wanted.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the API was recently improved to include [akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing$@delimiter%28delimiter:akka.util.ByteString,maximumFrameLength:Int,allowTruncation:Boolean%29:akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.util.ByteString,akka.util.ByteString,akka.NotUsed]). The documentation also contains an [example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-io.html#Accepting_connections__Echo_Server) of how to use it. Concerning your specific question:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Framing, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object TcpDelimiterBasedMessaging extends App {
  object chunks {
    val first = ByteString("Lorem Ipsum is simply.Dummy text of the printing.And typesetting industry.")
    val second = ByteString("More text.delimited by.a period.")
  }

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("delimiter-based-messaging", ConfigFactory.defaultReference())
  implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  Source(chunks.first :: chunks.second :: Nil)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("."), Int.MaxValue))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .runForeach(println)
    .onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
}
```

Produces the following output:

`Lorem Ipsum is simply
Dummy text of the printing
And typesetting industry
More text
delimited by
a period`

Comment: Perfect! This should be the accepted answer.

Also note that it will work across chunks. Try it with:

`val first = ByteString("Lorem Ipsum is simply.Dummy text of the printing.And typesetting")`


`val second = ByteString(" industry.More text.delimited by.a period.")`

Answer (score 2):

There is sample code that does something similar posted now in the Streams Cookbook in the akka-streams documentation at [Parsing lines from a stream of ByteStrings](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M3/scala/stream-cookbook.html#Parsing_lines_from_a_stream_of_ByteStrings).

Answer (score 2):

I think Andrey's use of `Framing` is the best solution to your question but I had a similar problem and found `Framing` to be too limited. I used `statefulMapConcat` instead which allows you to group your input ByteString using any rules you like. Here's the code for your question in case it helps anyone:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Flow, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString

object BasicTransformation extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatcher
  val data = ByteString("Lorem Ipsum is simply.Dummy text of the printing.And typesetting industry.")

  val grouping = Flow[Byte].statefulMapConcat { () =>
    var bytes = ByteString()
    byt =>
      if (byt == '.') {
        val string = bytes.utf8String
        bytes = ByteString()
        List(string)
      } else {
        bytes :+= byt
        Nil
      }
  }

  Source(data).via(grouping).runForeach(println).onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
}
```

Which produces:

`Lorem Ipsum is simply
Dummy text of the printing
And typesetting industry`